# Load Word file and fill it from the DataGridView and export it

Tags: c#, datagridview, export-to-word

I have a Word document with a header and I need to export the data from the DataGridView to this Word document.

Then I need to create an button to load the Word file and fill it with the data in the DataGridView.

Answer (score 0):

The best option for manipulating Office Documents from C# is using the [OpenXml SDK](https://www.nuget.org/packages/OpenXMLSDK-MOT/) and then open the word document using Process.Start. Use a class linked to your button to:

1. Create a word doc (in code)
2. Write out your table
3. Save the word doc to disk
4. Open the word doc Using Process.Start

Something like this:

```
using System.Diagnostics;
...
...
...
Process.Start(@"D:\Path\To\My\Word.docx");
```

Comment: i need to load an word file and export the data grid view to this word file

Comment: Ah - I understand now - try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29729413/export-datagridview-to-word-document-c-sharp